# How can I use the selectedIndex of a segmentedControl to get the corresponding index of array

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

My code:

```
class HomeViewController: UITableViewController {
    var segmentedControl: HMSegmentedControl!
    var text = [
        // 名词
        ["音读名词","训读名词","音读与训读的分辨方法"],
        // 形容词
        ["如何分辨形容词", "常用形容词", "形容词的变形规则"]
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configForSegmentedControl()
    }

    func configForSegmentedControl() {
        segmentedControl = HMSegmentedControl(sectionTitles: ["名词","形容词","形容动词","片假名单词","动词","复合动词"])
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, 44)
        segmentedControl.segmentEdgeInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)
        segmentedControl.selectionStyle = HMSegmentedControlSelectionStyleFullWidthStripe
        segmentedControl.selectionIndicatorLocation = HMSegmentedControlSelectionIndicatorLocationDown
        segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.segmentedControlChangedValue(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        if let font = UIFont(name: "BigYoungMediumGB2.0", size: 15) {
            segmentedControl.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(), NSFontAttributeName: font]
        }
        segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        segmentedControl.selectionIndicatorHeight = 3
        segmentedControl.selectionIndicatorColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        tableView.tableHeaderView = segmentedControl
    }

    func segmentedControlChangedValue(segmentedControl: HMSegmentedControl) {
        print("Selected index \(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) (via UIControlEventValueChanged)")
    }
}

extension HomeViewController {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return text[segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex].count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("cellForRowAtIndexPath:\(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = text[segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

And here is the console output:

> cellForRowAtIndexPath:0
>   cellForRowAtIndexPath:0
>   cellForRowAtIndexPath:0
>   Selected index 1 (via UIControlEventValueChanged)
>   Selected index 0 (via UIControlEventValueChanged)

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called before the `segmentedControlChangedValue` which is why I can't get the correct index to get the element of text array. So what should I do?

Comment: Do not post your code as an image. Please remove the image and copy and paste the actual code into your question (be sure you format it correctly). Also copy and paste the log output into your question instead of posting it as an image.

Comment: If you want value in cellForRow, then you should reload the tableview inside that 'segmentedControlChangedValue'

Comment: @Pyro  thank you ,it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference from comment:
If you want value in cellForRow, then you should reload the tableview inside that 'segmentedControlChangedValue'

In general case to set the the cell based on the selection/action, you should reload /beginUpdates the tableview as per requirement